# Building an upper triangular matrix recursively

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, matrix

Ive been breaking my head over trying to come up with a recursive way to build the following matrix in python. It is quite a challenge without pointers. Could anyone maybe help me out?

[image]

The recursion is the following:

```
T0 = 1,
Tn+1 = [[Tn, Tn],
        [ 0, Tn]]
```

I have tried many iterations of some recursive function, but I cannot wrap my head around it.

```
def T(n, arr):
    n=int(n)
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        c = 2**(n-1)
        Tn = np.zeros((c,c))
        Tn[np.triu_indices(n=c)] = self.T(n=n-1, arr=arr)
        return Tn
arr = np.zeros((8,8))
T(arr=arr, n=3)
```

Comment: Any pointers as to how to go about it? I have never dealt with recursion.

Comment: if you google python recursion, one of the first results is this: https://realpython.com/python-thinking-recursively/#recursive-functions-in-python, which describes how to do recursion in python

Comment: Thank you. I had found that site already, but those examples seem trivial compared to building this matrix. I wonder how you construct Tn, and how you parse Tn+1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not hard to do this, but you need to be careful about the meaning of the zero in the recursion. This isn't really precise for larger values of `n`:

```
Tn+1 = [[Tn, Tn],
        [ 0, Tn]]
```

Because that zero can represent a block of zeros for example on the second iteration you have this:

> [1, 1, 1, 1],
>    [0, 1, 0, 1],
>    [**0**, **0**, 1, 1],
>    [**0**, **0**, 0, 1]

Those four zeros in the bottom-left are all represented by the one zero in the formula. The block of zeros needs to be the same shape as the blocks around it.

After that it's a matter of making Numpy put thing in the right order and shape for you. [`numpy.block`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.block.html) is really handy for this and makes it pretty simple:

```
import numpy as np
def makegasket(n):
    if n == 0:
        return np.array([1], dtype=int)
    else:
        node = makegasket(n-1)
        return np.block([[node, node], [np.zeros(node.shape, dtype=int), node]])


makegasket(3)
```

Result:

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

If you use larger `n` you might enjoy `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow` for display:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow

# ....

imshow(makegasket(7))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a recursive function to implement this recursion. The idea is to start with the UR corner and build outward. You can even start with the UL corner to avoid some of the book-keeping and flip the matrix along either axis, but this won't be as efficient in the long run.

```
def build_matrix(n):
    size = 2**n

    # Depending on the application, even dtype=np.bool might work
    matrix = np.zeros((size, size), dtype=np.int)

    # This is t[0]
    matrix[0, -1] = 1

    for i in range(n):
        k = 2**i
        matrix[:k, -2 * k:-k] = matrix[k:2 * k, -k:] = matrix[:k, -k:]

    return matrix
```

Just for fun, here is a plot of timing results for this implementation vs [@Mark Meyer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56246201/2988730). It shows the slight timing advantage (also memory) of using a looping approach in this case:

[image]

Both algorithms run out of memory around n=15 on my machine, which is not too surprising.

Comment: haha, yes I found your implementation, but since the paper mentioned recursion, and so I wanted to see it for the heck of it. I had not found the np.block function, which makes it such a beautiful snippet! Thanks for the comparison + editing.